# Spark: Find pairs having at least n common attributes?

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset consisting of `(sensor_id, timestamp, data)` (the `sensor_id` are ids of IoT devices, timestamp is UNIX time and data is an MD5 hash of their output at that time). There is no primary key on the table but each row is unique.

I need to find all pairs of `sensor_id`s `s1` and `s2` such that these two sensors have at least `n` (`n=50`) entries `(timestamp, data)` in common between them i.e. on `n` different occasions they emitted same data at same timestamp.

For a sense of magnitudes of the data, I have 10B rows and ~50M distinct `sensor_ids` and I believe that there are around ~5M pairs of sensor-ids that emitted same data at same timestamp at least 50 times.

What's the best way to do this in Spark? I tried various approaches (group-by `(timestamp, data)` and/or self-joining) but they are prohibitively expensive in complexity.

Comment: can you add some example data, attempted code and expected output please.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pseudo-code, abstracting from Spark. You can sort your dataset first:

```
select id, timestamp, data order by timestamp, data, id
```

Exemplary 10 rows:

```
s1,100,a  #1
s2,100,a  #2
s3,100,a  #3
s4,100,b  #4
s1,101,a  #5
s3,101,b  #6
s4,101,b  #7
s2,101,a  #8
s3,102,b  #9
s4,102,b  #10
```

Now iterate top to bottom, and as long as the timestamp and data is the same as previous entry build a list of entries.

In our example rows 1-3 form such a list, so we see some potential pairs already:

```
s1, s2
s1, s3
s2, s3
```

Row #4 is just a single entry with (100,b), we can skip it. 
Row #5 only one entry with (101,a), we can skip it.

Row #6 and #7 are new pair:

```
s3, s4
```

Also #9 and #10 form a pair

Putting it all together one can easily count pairs:

```
s1, s2
s1, s3
s2, s3
s3, s4
s3, s4
```

The benefit of this method is that if you can sort the file, you can split the sorted dataset into multiple smaller chunks (the chunks should be splitted on the group boundaries - i.e. #1,2,3 should be in one chunk) , calculate the pairs, and join the final results as a last step.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct then I am able to achieve this by using the simple code below,

```scala
test("Spark: Find pairs having atleast n common attributes"){
/**
  * s1,1210283218710,34
    s1,1210283218730,24
    s1,1210283218750,84
    s1,1210283218780,54
    s2,1210283218710,34
    s2,1210283218730,24
    s2,1210283218750,84
    s2,1210283218780,54
    s3,1210283218730,24
    s3,1210283218750,84
    s3,1210283218780,54
  */
  val duplicateSensors = sc.textFile("sensor_data")
  .map(line => line.split(",")).map(ar=>((ar(1),ar(2)),ar(0) )) // (ts,val),sid
  .aggregateByKey(List.empty[String])(_ :+_,_:::_)// grouped(ts,val)(List(n sid))
  .flatMapValues(l => l.sorted.combinations(2))// (ts,val)(List(2 sid combination))
  .map(_._2).countByValue() // List(s1, s3) -> 3, List(s2, s3) -> 3, List(s1, s2) -> 4 (2sensors, no of common entries)
   // Now Do the filter .... grater than 50
  duplicateSensors.foreach(println)
}
```

And you will get the pairs with common attributes count.

Comment: This won't work on the size of dataset I mentioned. Specifically this O(s^2) where s is number of sensors.

Comment: @m69, I apologize.I am kind of new here . Removed the image . added code snippet. Thanks !

Comment: @Richard , fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, @RBanerjee!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

First, generate some fake data:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

fout = open('test_data.csv','w')

i=0
for x in range(100000):
  if i>=1000000:
    break
  for y in range(random.randint(0,100)):
    i         = i + 1
    timestamp = x
    sensor_id = random.randint(0,50)
    data      = random.randint(0,1000)
    fout.write("{} {} {}\n".format(timestamp,sensor_id,data))
```

Now, you can process the data as follows.

If you let the number of lines be *N*, the number of unique timestamps be *T*, and the expected number of sensors per timestamp be *S*, then the complexity of each operation is as in the comments

```py
import itertools

#Turn a set into a list of all unique unordered pairs in the set, without
#including self-pairs
def Pairs(x):
  temp = []
  x    = list(x)
  for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
      temp.append((x[i],x[j]))
  return temp

#Load data
#O(N) time to load data
fin        = sc.textFile("file:///z/test_data.csv")
#Split data at spaces, keep only the timestamp and sensorid portions
#O(N) time to split each line of data
lines      = fin.map(lambda line: line.split(" ")[0:2])
#Convert each line into a timestamp-set pair, where the set contains the sensor
#O(N) time to make each line into a timestamp-hashset pair
monosets   = lines.map(lambda line: (line[0],set(line[1])))
#Combine sets by timestamp to produce a list of timestamps and all sensors at
#each timestamp
#O(TS) time to place each line into a hash table of size O(T) where each 
#entry in the hashtable is a hashset combining 
timegroups = sets.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a | b)
#Convert sets at each timestamp into a list of all pairs of sensors that took
#data at that timestamp
#O(T S^2) time to do all pairs for each timestamp
shared     = timegroups.flatMap(lambda tg: PairsWithoutSelf(tg[1]))
#Associate each sensor pair with a value one
#O(T S^2) time
monoshared = shared.map(lambda x: (x,1))
#Sum by sensor pair
#O(T S^2) time
paircounts = monoshared.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
#Filter by high hitters
#O(<S^2) time
good       = paircounts.filter(lambda x: x[1]>5)
#Display results
good.count()
```

The time complexities are a little hand-wavy as I'm working on this answer kind of late, but the bottlenecks should be visible, at least.